# Highlight corresponding table <TD> cell based on row name and cell value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How would I go about highlighting a cell based on the row name and column value from the first column?  I have included a fiddle.

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
    var currentValue = $(this).find('th').text();
    var currentValue2 = $(this).find('td').text();
    if(('Value 1' == currentValue) && ('Value 1' == currentValue2)) {           
        $(this).addClass('highlight');            
    }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test2</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alsjka/entumojr/

Comment: I am unclear what result you want to receive. Can you clarify the desired end result?

Comment: You're are looking for `currentValue == Value1` but `Value1` is inside a `td` and not a `th`

Comment: I am trying to highlight the cell that corresponds ... if (as an example) when  columnheader = "test" and Column[1] row = "Value 1" then "12" would be highlighted.  Thanks i hope i explained it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a lot more complicated that what you wrote bro,

your algorithm is wrong for what you want
you want this: if a heading has "One" text in it and the td has the same "One" text (or any desired text) you want to add highlight class to td

so your search should not begin from `tr` elements, but from `th` elements

and forEach `th` elements you need to traverse all `tr` elements looking for a `td` having the same(or any desired) text

i've changed your code a little and this is the result

```
$('th').each(function(index,item) {        
      var currentValue = $(item).text();      
      $('tr').each(function(index,item){
        var tdElements = $(item).find("td");
        tdElements.each( function(index,item){        
            var currentValue2 = $(item).text();                      
            if(('test' == currentValue) && ('Value 1' == currentValue2)) {  
                $(this).addClass('highlight');
                $(this).next().addClass('highlight2')
            }
        })
      })          
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mahdiar_mansouri/txo2jpmq/11/

=========

based on your new comment I think you want next element of the match to be selected so i've updated it a little, check out the fiddle for best result and see if it is what you wanted

===========

UPDATED

based on your last comment
You want corresponding TH and first TD of a row

This snippet can help you do that

```
$('th').each(function(index,item) {        
  var currentValue = $(item).text();      
  $('tr').each(function(index2,item){
    var tdElements = $(item).find("td");
    if(tdElements.first().text() == "Value 2" && currentValue == 'test8' ){
        tdElements.eq(index).addClass('highlight');
    } 
  })
```

});

Here's the fiddle of it

http://jsfiddle.net/mahdiar_mansouri/06ygpzqd/3/

Comment: Wow that look great!!  Thank you so much and yes i am no means good at Jquery.  I see the row is highlighted; how would i just highlight only the cell and not the entire row?       

Please see my updated Fiddle..Based on your changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/alsjka/entumojr/18/

And thanks so much

Comment: You're welcome, Mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem please,, it's not selecting entire row, only one ```td``` is highlighted in your new fiddly,, in my fiddle i didn't know you want to select matched ```td``` or the td next to it, so i created two highlight classes and set each of them to one of the td elements

Comment: In my new fiddle I highlighted the expected cell in green.  The yellow cell is not the expected result. Thanks

Comment: Yea i got what you want, check the answer I've updated it, please mark it as accepted if it solved your problem or let me know if otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute an answer to my OP.  Thanks for all answers and suggestions..

http://jsfiddle.net/alsjka/81sy27d4/88/

```
--Css to highlight table cell
.highlight {
    background: green;
}
--find table header index by cell name using "TH"
var row = $("#tab").find("th:contains('tblh2')").closest('th').index();
--Find non header index by cell name using "TD"
var col = $("#tab").find("td:contains('tblh3')").closest('tr').index();
--Script to use the found indexes and highlight the cell 
$('table tr:eq(' + row + ') td:eq(' + col + ')').addClass('highlight');
--Sample table
    <table border="2" width="200" id="tab">

  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>tblh1</th>
    <th>tblh2</th>
    <th>tblh3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>tblh1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>tblh2</span></td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>tblh3</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).